# Add formula leads to #NAME? error

Tags: formula, phpexcel

I'm trying to add some formulas to an excel sheet, but every formula shows only "#NAME?". But when I click on one formula field, into the function editor and out of it again, it uses the formula correct. You have any ideas, what could lead to this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Try adding formula using its native equivalent `=SUM()`. `=SUMME()` is obviously localized variant.

Comment: Yes that was it, that was easy, thanks!

Comment: See section 4.6.5 (entitled "Locale Settings for Formulae") for details of how to use `SUMME` in your formula instead of the English `SUM`